# does CloudWatch dashboard change dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, rhel, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using custom CloudWatch config to pull disk read/write info from RHEL Linux servers, which is working good.

But recently did some clean up on Linux servers - delete old file systems.

Since then, CloudWatch not showing graph on deleted old file systems disks - which is expected.

But my question - why CloudWatch agent not recognizing few disks not exist in server anymore and deleting it from CloudWatch dashboard?

Or how do I update cloud watch dashboard update dynamically without me going around each server dashboard and removing deleted disk metrics manually?